# How to use background on a single row or column in table?

Tags: tables, context

When using simple tables in Context (\starttable command), can one place a background on specific rows and/or columns?

Comment: The \starttable command is considered deprecated except for the most basic tables (see the overview at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tables_Overview). For what you want, it's better to use "natural tables" (with html-like syntax) or the new xtables environment. Both have their own manuals.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas said, it is much easier to use "Natural Tables". For simple tables, you can still use the old table syntax. Here is an example:

```
\definecolor[lightblue][r=0.8,g=0.8,b=1]
\definecolor[lightred][r=1,g=0.8,b=0.8]

\startsetups table:color
  \setupTABLE[row][2][background=color, backgroundcolor=lightblue]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][background=color, backgroundcolor=lightred]
\stopsetups

\starttext
  \startTABLE[setups={table:color}]
  \NC One \NC Two \NC Three \NC Four \NC \NR
  \NC One \NC Two \NC Three \NC Four \NC \NR
  \NC One \NC Two \NC Three \NC Four \NC \NR
  \NC One \NC Two \NC Three \NC Four \NC \NR
  \stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]